# how to set a click listener of the icon in alert dialog android?

Tags: android

I face a problem when i want to set a listener when clicking on the icon in the alert dialog, is there any method to achieve that?

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder materialAlertDialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder((new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.material_design_theme)))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setTitle("Vérification d'E-Mail")
            .setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_return_512))
            .setMessage("Vérifier l'existence d'un compte e-mail que vous avez nous envoyé");
```

Comment: In material there is no listener for icon. You have Postive, Negative and Neutral button click listeners.If you really want an icon click listener then you would have create your custom dialog and layout. 
For more information on what methods are available on MaterialAlertDialog you can checkout [MaterialAlertDialogBuilder](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/dialog/MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.java) Class.

Comment: Try looking at [Create Custom Alert Dialog in Android](https://medium.com/android-beginners/create-reusable-alert-dialog-in-android-bd0b84487675).